# Inserting arguments as part of another argument in bash alias or function

Tags: bash

I'd like to make a bash function (or alias) like:

```
function warmup() { ab -n100 http://$1.myapp.appspot.com/ ;}
```

But I get:

```
$ warmup some_version
ab -n 1000 -c 5 http://.myapp.appspot.com/ some_version
```

What am I doing wrong? Is this possible?

Comment: Could you please post your entire code from the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me in bash 4.2.10, it might not work on an older version. Try upgrading yours.

Comment: Indeed, this was due to OS X shipping with 3.2.48(1)-release, thanks!

Comment: Works for me in bash version 3.2.48(1)-release (in OS X 10.8.3), as well as 2.05b.0(1)-release (OS X 10.4.11). Whatever the problem was, it's not the bash version.